# Como puedo configurar variables de entorno dentro de docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Saludos colegas, Estoy intentando configurar un archivo `docker-compose.yml`, con los siguientes comandos:

```
nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    -  /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    env_file: .env_development
    restart: always
    build: ./postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: ${POSTGRES_IP}


  web:
    env_file: .env_development
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    volumes:
      - /home/kalismash/Docker/app_django/web/app:/home/julian_develop/apps
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: ${DJANGO_IP}
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```

Adicional al archivo tengo otro archivo `.env` el cual contiene todas las variables de entorno, es el siguiente:

```
#Set of enviroments global
LANG=es_CO.utf8
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELL2=/bin/sh
TERM=xterm


#Postgress environment

PG_SERVICE=postgres
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
POSTGRES_USER=develop_julian
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgress
POSTGRES_DB=django
ENVIROMENT=Development
ENVPORT=5432
POSTGRES_IP=172.25.0.9

#Django environment

USER=django_develop
SECRET_KEY=6g_,p?@$/t+Kgfy8c=BC*zQPNM*eJ,qZ&*@iL>9Q
DJANGO_IP=172.25.0.8
```

Cuando intento correr `docker-compose up web postgres` obtengo la siguiente advertencia:

> WARNING: The POSTGRES_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
>   string. WARNING: The IP_POSTGRES variable is not set. Defaulting to a
>   blank string.

Intenté seguir la documentación de `docker` [Docker enviroment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) pero no logro que funcione correctamente, además también intenté hacerlo por `args`, porque `docker` advierte sobre el proceso de `build`

> Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in
>   environment files will not be automatically visible during the build.
>   Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment
>   variables.

Pero tampoco consigo realizar la configuración de variables de entorno, si alguien se ha enfrentado a este problema apreciaría bastante su ayuda, muchas gracias colegas.

Comment: Logre resolver la pregunta formulada, resulta que para acceder a los valores de las variables de entorno se puede hacer mediante `"$variable"`  .  Adicional a ello también debes configurar tu archivo con el nombre `.env`  de otra forma no me pudo funcionar,Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir tu solución como respuesta? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debes incluir la propiedad `env`: En tu archivo de *docker-compose* y definir el archivo **.env** allí. El archivo **.env** debe estar al mismo nivel que el **docker-compose.yml**. Dentro del archivo **.env**, defines las variables de la manera tradicional, `VAR=VALUE;`. Luego, dentro de *docker-compose* sólo llamas la variable.

Algo así:

> Aquí defines el ***env file***:

```
version: '2'    
services:
  postgres:
    env_file: .env
```

> Asumiendo que tu directorio de trabajo es **$HOME**, tendrías que colocar tu archivo **.env** allí:

```
cat $HOME/.env
VAR=foo
```

> Recuerda que **docker-compose.yml** debe estar al mismo nivel, es decir, en **$HOME** también. Así, puedes usar tus variables, en el archivo **compose**:

```
version: '2'    
services:
  postgres:
    env_file: .env
    container_name: "$VAR"
```